# Module Not in Gradle View

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have a module open in the Project view but it's not in the Gradle view.  When I try to import the module into the Gradle view I get "The project is already registered."  How do I get the module into the Gradle view?

Comment: Is it a multi module project? If no, you could remove all IDE related data (.idea folder amd .iml file) and import project from build.gradle again.

Comment: It is a multi module project